# Numbers related query

Tags: python, numbers

What's the meaning of `"L"` behind any number`(e.g 153L=?,648L=?)`

I am getting the value `2432902008176640000L` while i am typing `math.factorial(20)` in python2.7 interpreter.

May be some ppl find it a silly question but i dont know anything about this "L" thing.So please help me to increase my knowledge.

Comment: `Long` integer: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It 's a `Long` integer. More about it, in the **[Python docs: 5.4. Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex)**

Answer (score 2):

It means that the number is a [`long` Integer](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), and can store larger numbers.

Comment: Not only larger, infinitely large.

Comment: Well, infinite isn't completely true either. At some point, you will run out of memory.

Comment: Yeah, "infinite precision" is used but "unlimited" might be a better word.

Answer (score 0):

That means the number is a `Long`, meaning it is stored using more bytes and can contain larger values